# Low Search Errors on upgrade to 3.5.1

Tags: low-search, low

We've just updated a site to use LS3.5.1 from 3.3.2 and I'm getting the following errors. EE is 2.9.0 - an upgrade is an option as the site is brand new.

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: 7
>
> Filename: keywords/lsf.keywords.php
>
> Line Number: 869

We're using Structure, so for the link to the page we want to use `{page_uri}`. The results are all working as expected - we're just getting these errors.

I've been into each collection and added the language option. I've re-indexed the collections and switching `{page_uri}` for `{auto_path}` removes the error notices.

I've also deleted the module entirely and re-uploaded to make sure we're not missing anything in the filters folder which I've seen could be an issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get the error fixed in the next version. For now, open up /low_search/filters/keywords/lsf.keywords.php and look up line #869, which reads:

```
$row['auto_path'] = $this->_urls[$row['channel_id']] . $row['url_title'];
```

Change that to:

```
$row['auto_path'] = @$this->_urls[$row['channel_id']] . $row['url_title'];
```

Note the `@` added before `$this->`.